# Why do I keep getting the "AttributeError: lower not found" error when using a Vectorizer command?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, nlp, tfidfvectorizer

I'm trying to set up a text classification model, that can split text into two categories. I've checked the shape of my arrays, and they're of the (n, ) format. But when I run my vectorizer command, I seem to run into this error. Any advice would be appreciated :)

```
x,y = dfclean\['text'\],dfclean\['class'\]

x.shape

> output = (19998,)
* * *

vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=50,max_features=5000)

x =  vectorizer.fit(x)
> AttributeError: lower not found
```

Answer (score 0):

The Attribute error of type lower is probably occurring because you are trying to fit the vectorizer on your text data directly.
I suggest to try to use the fit_transform method instead of the fit method.
Such as:

```
x_tfidf = vectorizer.fit_transform(x)
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much!

Comment: okay, never mind, it just immediately stopped working. getting the same error :/ gonna have to figure something out

Comment: This is not correct; there is no way `.fit_transform` would rectify such an issue with `.fit` - the latter is used as the first stage of `.fit_transform` in any case.